# Efficiently color vertices in modern OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am programming a GUI to accompany my algorithms. The GUI elements I use need to represent various elements (think: maps with key elements and high-lit edges, vector fields) with as little computational overhead as I can manage.

Given a drawing involving a set of triangles defined by hundreds of vertices and indices, and between 3 and 5 discrete colors applied to them based on their 'role' within the drawing. How do I make my GUI elements take the desired color with as little waste in computational power possible? E.g. a wall has to be *col1*, an entry point is denoted by *col2*, etc.

I have identified three ways to go about this by reading up, and while I suspect one option to be optimal, I would like to know if this is correct, or if there is a part of the puzzle I am missing?

1. Every vertex consists of 6 (or 7, in the feasible scenario that alpha channels are also varied) GLfloat fields. The fragment shader takes the last vec3/vec4 and uses this to apply color. This sounds wasteful to me, as it logically uses 3 (or 4) *n* worth of GLfloat fields to describe much less intricate details than a highly varied colour space.
2. Every vertex contains its position (3 GLfloat fields) and one GLuint, with the GLuint encoding for a color. Separately, a set of uniform color variables is defined. The fragment shader contains a makeshift switch statement (= if/else list) which allows the shader to translate the GLuint field into an instruction for a specific uniform color to be used. This method sounds most practical to me, but I have no idea how 'heavy' 3-4 if-statements are on the GPU.
3. The fragment shader has only one uniform color. Every separately-colored element is drawn by first changing the uniform color, and then drawing the following element. As I'm told passing data to the GPU in small batches is slow, this sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: I'd consider method IIa as well: pass the palette index as a GLuint, but use it directly to index into an uniform array of vec4 colours.

Comment: The answer depends on how constant your data is. If colors change ever so rarely then method 1 is the fastest, but will turn slow every time you need to update all the colors (and penalty might be big if you have very many vertices)

Comment: I agree with @Quentin, if your hardware supports uniform arrays, then indexing will be a very neat solution, practically no overhead

Comment: The option @Quentin shows slipped under my radar, that sounds like it is exactly what I need, thank you!

Comment: You can pass the colors as a 4-element array (or struct) of GLubyte / GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE. That will take up only 4 bytes. Unless you're interested in HDR, that is enough to represent all possible SDR colors.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What is wrong with just making it a vertex attribute like most people do?

Comment: @user253751 slow to update for all vertices